# Google is able to track me through Tor

Tags: windows, google

I've just moved from Brave to Tor Browser, because YouTube has been able to track me for the last little while, even though I deleted cookies, USING A VPN, etc.. (Adding recommendations of channels I haven't watched in weeks. Imagine a 90% English feed with 10% recommendations of local news channels I watch from time to time.) It once recommended me a channel that I last watched, BEFORE reinstalling my PC. And its not like I was looking up similar topics or something. Imagine your watching 4 coding tutorials, your recommendations are full with coding tutorials and YouTube is recommending you a baseball video all of a sudden.

So I started up Tor. BUT THE SAME RESULT! YouTube gives me 50% English and 50% of my native language. Most of them are channels I watch btw. When going to google.com the side was in another language (the one I was routing my traffic through.)

What black magic is google using to track me?
(Using Win10, en-US)

Edit: I just tried Tails, but got similar YouTube results. So it seems to be some kind of hardware identification??

Answer (score 1):

Hardware fingerprinting is used, but like that. And your setup and case sounds like a login leak: i.e. you've logged in somewhere like in Google/Youtube and it keeps tracking you. That's why a disposable VM is the only way to be 101% ensured that this kind of situation will never happen. Use Qubes OS with it's disposable VM's feature or a VirtualBox - but you will need to make some scripts to start a new **blank** disposable VM for you